# Melhoramento no CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou criando um CSS simples próprio apenas para ser usado na criação de app cordova.

Estou tendo dificuldades para caso queira colocar as colunas em linhas.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.col-1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
}

.col-2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.col-3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 75%;
}

.col-4 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.btn2{
    background: #3f51b5;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 53px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 17px;
}.btn2:active{
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.mr-1{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="assets/imgs/foto.png" alt="foto" class="responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 mr-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-foto">Foto</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn2 red btn-foto-apagar">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

O codigo acima gera essa parte destacada em vermelho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Questão:

Como fazer para que a imagem ocupe toda a largura e os dois botões fique abaixo da imagem lado a lado.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor forma seria tirar a div que possui a sua imagem de dentro da div que tem a class row

```
<div class="col-4">
    <img src="assets/imgs/foto.png" alt="foto" class="responsive">
</div>
<div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-2 mr-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-foto">Foto</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn2 red btn-foto-apagar">X</button>
    </div>
</div>
```